# Scipy.stats.sem calculate of standard error

Tags: python, scipy, standard-error

Why am I getting different results?

```
from scipy.stats import sem
import numpy as np
l = [0,2,4,5,6,7]
print(sem(l))
print(np.std(l)/np.sqrt(len(l)))
```

> 1.0645812948447542
>
> 0.9718253158075502

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scipy.stats.sem` function uses a default value of `ddof=1` for the number-of-degrees-of-freedom parameter while `numpy.std` uses `ddof=0` by default. This is also highlighted in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sem.html):

> The default value for ddof is different to the default (0) used by other ddof containing routines, such as np.std and np.nanstd.

Consequently you get:

```py
>>> print(sem(l))
1.06458129484
>>> print(sem(l, ddof=0))
0.971825315808
>>> print(sem(l, ddof=1))
1.06458129484

>>> print(np.std(l)/np.sqrt(len(l)))
0.971825315808
>>> print(np.std(l, ddof=0)/np.sqrt(len(l)))
0.971825315808
>>> print(np.std(l, ddof=1)/np.sqrt(len(l)))
1.06458129484
```